# Проблема с fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Всем привет!
Изучаю android по книге HeadFirst
Возникла проблема

Это onCreate MainActivity

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WorkoutDetailFragment fragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment)
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
        fragment.setWorkout(1);
    }
```

Это xml fragment:

```
<fragment
    class="workout.hfad.com.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment"
    android:id="@+id/detail_frag"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Ругается на строчку

```
    <WorkoutDetailFragment fragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment) 
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
```

И выдаёт ошибку:

```
    `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 
'workout.hfad.com.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment'
```

Собственно, всё делал по книге (вроде). В чём ошибка?

Comment: Видимо у вас `WorkoutDetailFragment` не расширяет `Fragment`

Comment: public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment 

Расширяет

Comment: Вообще приведённый вами способ добавления фрагмента плох, ибо багован, негибок и, засим, не используется. Обычно фрагменты добавляют программно. В этом конкретном случае ещё может помочь поиск по ID контейнера, в котором расположен тег с фрагментом, вместо поиска по ID самого тега фрагмента.

Comment: Так Вы расширяете `android.app.Fragment` или `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`? Если используете из support, то и `Activity` должна быть оттуда же и `getSupportFragmentManager()` должен использоваться.

Comment: Да, проблема была в том, что я расширял android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Спасибо!